# Internet explorer only executing function inside jQuery ajax success response once even though there are three requests

Tags: javascript, ajax, internet-explorer, jquery

I have a function that uses jQuery.load() to call in 3 snippets of forms from different pages and then on the success text status it tries to load a colour picker:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    function ajax_form(putloadingboxhere, putsnippethere, snippeturl) {

        $(putsnippethere).load(snippeturl, function (responseText, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest, ) {
            if (textStatus == "success") {
                alert('One')
                $("input.pickcolor").ColorPicker({
                    onShow: function (colpkr) {
                        $(colpkr).fadeIn(500);
                        return false;
                    },
                    onSubmit: function(hsb, hex, rgb, el) {
                        $(el).val(hex);
                        $(el).ColorPickerHide();
                        $(el).siblings('.colorpreview').css('background-color', '#' + hex);
                    },
                    onBeforeShow: function () {
                        $(this).ColorPickerSetColor(this.value);
                    }
                })
                .bind('keyup', function(){
                    $(this).ColorPickerSetColor(this.value);
                });  

                alert('Two')
            }
            if (textStatus == "error") {
                // Show error message
            }
        });
    }

    ajax_form('tab_box', '#formone', 'snippet_one.htm #snippet');
    ajax_form('tab_box', '#formtwo', 'snippet_two_copy.htm #snippet');
    ajax_form('tab_box', '#formthree', 'snippet_three.htm #snippet');
});
```

It works fine in Firefox and Safari but (surprise, surprise) IE has a problem with it. I have added an alert to see what is going on before and after one of the functions.

FF & Safari & IE8: Alert 'one' and Alert 'two' appear three times as expected and colour picker appears.
IE6 & 7: Alert 'one' shows three times and colour picker does not appear.

Any help would be great! Cheers.

EDIT

The line IE is referring to when it throws this error:
'Error: Object doesn't support this property or method.' 
is:

$('input.pickcolor').ColorPicker

Anyone got any insights? Thanks

Comment: Since 'one' pops up three times, that seems to be a problem with creating the ColorPicker three times. There should be a javascript error, because it seem to abort ...

Comment: I turned on Script Errors in IE and get this response after every alert - 'Error: Object doesn't support this property or method.' I had a look at http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308260 but nothing seemed relevant. Are you able to shed any light on what that could mean? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tied ".live" instead of ".bind"?

Comment: **Quick update:** _As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated._ [jQuery API->.live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/). You should instead use `.on()`to attach event handlers. `.on()` offers improvements on speed too as it does not need to go through whole DOM tree when finding something at top of DOM (buttons and links is usually placed on top). [jQuery API->.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

Answer (score 0):

I just test the script and the only problem I had is that the function "load" has a comma in the last parameter, It works fine in IE6 and IE7.

```
$(putsnippethere).load(snippeturl, function (responseText, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest, )
```

Update all script:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/colorpicker.css" type="text/css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" type="text/css" href="css/layout.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/colorpicker.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/eye.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/utils.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/layout.js?ver=1.0.2"></script>
    <title>load</title>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="formone"></div>
    <div id="formtwo"></div>
    <div id="formthree"></div>

    <input id="i1" class="pickcolor" type="text" /><br />
    <input id="i2" class="pickcolor" type="text" /><br />
    <input id="i3" class="pickcolor" type="text" /><br />

    <pre style="text-align:left;width:600px;" id="mydebug"></pre>

</body>
</html>
<script>
$(function() {

    addDebug = function(text){
        $("#mydebug").append(text+"<br />");
    }

  function ajax_form(putloadingboxhere, putsnippethere, snippeturl) {

    $(putsnippethere).load(snippeturl, function (responseText, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
      if (textStatus == "success") {

          addDebug(putsnippethere  + " :: One");

          var lstElPickcolor = $("input.pickcolor");

          addDebug(putsnippethere  + " :: Length inputs : " + lstElPickcolor.length);

          $.each(lstElPickcolor, function(i, val){

              addDebug(putsnippethere  + " :: add ColorPicker for input.id=" + $(val).attr('id'));
                        $(val).ColorPicker({

                  onShow: function (colpkr) {
                      $(colpkr).fadeIn(500);
                      return false;
                  },

                  onSubmit: function(hsb, hex, rgb, xel) {
                      $(xel).val(hex);
                      $(xel).ColorPickerHide();
                      $(xel).siblings('.colorpreview').css('background-color', '#' + hex);
                  },

                  onBeforeShow: function () {
                      $(this).ColorPickerSetColor(this.value);
                  }
              });

              addDebug(putsnippethere  + " :: unbind event keyup for input.id=" + $(val).attr('id'));
              $(val).unbind('keyup');

              addDebug(putsnippethere  + " :: bind event keyup for input.id=" + $(val).attr('id'));
              $(val).bind('keyup', function(){
                  $(this).ColorPickerSetColor(this.value);
              });               

          });

          addDebug(putsnippethere  + " :: Two");
          addDebug(" ");
      }

      if (textStatus == "error") {
          // Show error message
      }

    });
  }

  ajax_form('tab_box', '#formone', 'snippet_one.htm #snippet');
  ajax_form('tab_box', '#formtwo', 'snippet_two_copy.htm #snippet');
  ajax_form('tab_box', '#formthree', 'snippet_three.htm #snippet');

});
</script>
```

Comment: Hi Andres,

Thanks for your help, I removed that comma, but it still didn't work. Interestingly enough though, when I copied and tested your code above, I got the same thing happen in Firefox as IE - only the alert 'One' appears three times. Can you think of a reason for that?

Comment: Actually, ignore that, it's still doing the same thing as it was before. 1&2x3 in FF and only 1x3 in IE7.

Comment: Oh, hang on, the input.pickcolor are bought in via the ajax - they are in a form that is a snippet bought into the page by ajax.

Comment: please try this and see the results

Comment: It still has the same results - works fine in FF in both the input fields that are bought in with the ajax and the input fields that are native to the page and in IE neither work - Just get one, one, one alerted. 'Error: Object doesn't support this property or method.' is shown after each alert in IE.